# Mapping Azure Service Fabric services to a certain node type

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

Creating services (or actors in the case of Reliable Actors) in the Service Fabric application VS template is effortless. Defining node types in the Azure portal is also easy. But how do you map a service/actor to run on a specific node type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using placement constraints.

More information on that can be found in the "Placement constraints and node properties" section of [this](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description/) article.

In short, you'd need to set placement properties on your cluster and then set placement constraints on the service using [StatefulServiceDescription.PlacementConstraints](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.description.servicedescription.placementconstraints.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Here is declarative way to do it in ApplicationManifest.xml:

```
<ServiceTypes>
  <StatelessServiceType ServiceTypeName="Stateless1">
    <PlacementConstraints>(NodeTypeName==BackEnd)</PlacementConstraints>
  </StatelessServiceType>
</ServiceTypes>
```

And you can use parameters to use different constraints in different environments:

```
<Service Name="Stateless1">
  <StatelessService ServiceTypeName="Stateless1Type" InstanceCount="[Stateless1_InstanceCount]">
    <SingletonPartition />
    <PlacementConstraints>[Stateless1_PlacementConstraints]</PlacementConstraints>
  </StatelessService>
</Service>
```

Stateless1_PlacementConstraints can be redefined in application parameters files (Cloud.xml, Local5Node.xml etc).

More details:
https://brentdacodemonkey.wordpress.com/2016/09/11/placement-constraints-with-service-fabric/

Comment: Instead of `(NodeTypeName==...)` use `(NodeType==...)`. Otherwise, this worked great for me. If instantiating a service using the PowerShell `New-ServiceFabricService` commandlet then there's a `-PlacementConstraint` parameter for you to use.

Comment: I found it more convenient to use constrains like (IsBackendNode==...) in this case I can easily configure clusters with just one node type (for testing and such) and still satisfy placement constrains, while in case of (NodeType==...) you would always need pre-configured number of node types.