# What's the difference between primary and non-primary nodes in Azure Service Fabric?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

I can't find any specific documentation that says what's the difference between primary node and a non-primary node, and how are they being used. Can somebody shed light on it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having multiple node types can be useful in these situations:

- You want to run services exposed to the internet & services not exposed. The first set would run on a node type (VMSS) attached to the Load Balancer and the second on a scale set that isn't.
- You need to run services for certain customers on premium hardware and trials on cheaper hardware. The first set would run on nodes with lots of CPU, lots of RAM. The second on lower SKU's.
- You want to build a cluster that exceeds the max node count that one VMSS can hold.
  Or you need to add scale sets on the fly, to support huge growth.

And: The primary nodes run your system services, the secondaries don't.

Answer (score 4):

If you compare **Service Fabric** to other Orchestration Tools like *Kubernetes*, you will notice a small difference on how clusters are defined.

Kubernetes uses a concept of **Master** to host cluster management services, and **Minion** to host your application services(containers). Until version 1.1 it was not possible to run containers on the masters, because it had the idea that ***Master***'s should be isolated to avoid conflicting with containers running on it, like consuming too much memory, disk, cpu, and so on.

On **Service Fabric** this is a bit different. When you define a [*NodeType*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-nodetypes) as [***Primary***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity#the-properties-of-each-node-type), what it means inside the cluster is that this *NodeType* will be responsible to host the Service Fabric Management Services(services needed to control the cluster health, orchestration and so on).

When you deploy a cluster via Azure Portal, depending on the durability tier (Bronze,Silver,Gold) you choose, it will require a certain number of nodes on Primary Node Type, to keep the cluster management healthy. For production workloads, 5 nodes the minimum recommended size for *Primary NodeType* or NonPrimary with stateful workloads in it. The minimum supported use VM SKU is Standard D1 or Standard D1_V2.

There is a catch for Primary Node-type, the change of VMSS Sku (Size) is not supported, you can do on your own risk, but is a recipe for disaster, because the risk of loosing management services is too high.

***Non-primary NodeType***, there is no overall difference other than these mentioned above. All NodeTypes will have a VMSS and a LoadBalancer(with an domain) being able to configure the access rules. All NodeType will have a limit of 100 nodes.

Compared to Kubernetes, SF does not add any constraints to prevent you deploying your services alongside the management services on primary nodes, Every node is part of a pool  of resources(including the primary). So the default behaviour is deploy applications on every node available no matter the NodeType.

When you plan bigger clusters (100+ nodes), it is important that you take that in account, and isolate your Primary NodeType from your workloads, and remove the pressure on your management services nodes.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much of a difference. Nodes of different node types all share the same characteristics of a Service Fabric Cluster. They all participate in load balancing etc.
Except for one thing: system services run om the nodes of the primairy node type only ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-capacity#primary-node-type---capacity-guidance)):

> Primary node type is where the system services run, so the VM SKU you choose for it, must take into account the overall peak load you plan to place into the cluster. Here is an analogy to illustrate what I mean here - Think of the primary node type as your "Lungs", it is what provides oxygen to your brain, and so if the brain does not get enough oxygen, your body suffers.

An important purpose of node types is to constraint service placement to specific node types. For example, you can have several node types, one uses VM's with higher cpu capacity and one with focus on amount of memory. The you can place memory resource hungry services on one node type and cpu intensive services on the other.

Comment: thanks!
I also found out how to map an application/service to run on a specific node type.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36726231/mapping-azure-service-fabric-services-to-a-certain-node-type